# Почему не получается установить APK приложение в Windows 11

Tags: adb

скачал под систему Anroid для Windows 11

Установил ADB

Пишу в Power Shell: `.\adb connect 127.0.0.1:58526`

ADB подключается

Пишу: `.\adb install "Путь до APK файла"`

Появляется такая ошибка:

> Performing Push Install adb: error: failed to get feature set: more than one device/emulator

Answer (score 1):

Запроси список устройств-эмуляторов `adb devices`

Затем выполни установку, указывая явно нужное устройство (ключ `-s`)